# What is wrong with this query (select ... where in (select ...)?

Tags: mysql, select

**iplist table** (id, username, ip, created) - stores the distinct IP addresses of each user

I want to find all the usernames who ever had the same IP address as 'angryuser'

MySQL QUERY:

```
    SELECT  username,
        ip  
FROM    `iplist` 
WHERE   ip  IN (
                    SELECT  ip 
                    FROM    iplist 
                    WHERE   username='angryuser'
                )
```

If I run this query it gets in a loop and kills my server :)

Why?

**Update:**

Here's the execution plan:

```
id  select_type         table   type  possible_keys  key   key_len  ref   rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             iplist  ALL   NULL           NULL  NULL     NULL  102757  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  iplist  ALL   NULL           NULL  NULL     NULL  102757  Using where
```

Comment: Please probvider result of `EXPLAIN SELECT username,ip FROM iplist WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip FROM iplist WHERE username='angryuser')` command

Comment: id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra

1  PRIMARY  iplist  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  102757  Using where

2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  iplist  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  102757  Using where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a normal **INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT  p.username,
        p.ip
FROM    iplist p INNER JOIN
        iplist s ON p.ip = s.ip
WHERE   s.username='angryuser'
```

Ensure that you have the correct indexes on the table as previously mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot!This is the simplest way with the indexes suggested by Quassnoi

Answer (score 1):

Well, the query should run fine. There's most likely another problem here. Do you have any indexes on your table, and how large IS your table?

Answer (score 1):

For a bit of a backgrounder on why the original subquery performs slower then the Join, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a composite index on `(ip, username)`

`MySQL` tries to optimize your query into this:

```
SELECT  ip, username
FROM    iplist ui
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    iplist uo
        WHERE   uo.username = 'angry'
                AND uo.id = ui.id
        )
```

The inner `EXISTS` (that needs to be evaluated for each row from users) will require but a single index scan if you create this index.

However, it is better to rewrite the query like that:

```
SELECT  io.username, io.ip
FROM    iplist ia
JOIN    iplist io
ON      io.ip = ia.ip
WHERE   ia.username = 'angryuser'
        AND io.username <> 'angryuser'
```

This way, the `'angryuser'` query will be made leading and the engine will need to check only several `IPs`.

The index on `(ip, username)` you should create anyway for this to work fast.

**Update:**

If your usernames are too long, you need to create a prefixed index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_iplist_ip_username ON (ip, username (30))
```

`30` characters is enough for this index to be selective.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `iplist` ADD INDEX ( `ip` , `username` ) ; - 
#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: I created index on username and ip individually and now the query runs in 8 secs - not good enough

Comment: `@hamlet`: you need a composite index. Create a prefixed index if your usernames are that long. See the post update.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the sub-query is returning a large resultset:

```
SELECT  ip 
FROM    iplist 
WHERE   username='angryuser'
```

Answer (score -1):

Why shouldn't you use:

```
SELECT username, ip FROM iplist WHERE username='angryuser'
```

It does the same

Comment: Doesn't do the same at all... one gets any ip that angryuser has used, the other gets any usernames that have come from any ip that angryuser has used.